# Adding resolve to Angular ui-router nested views?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a version on my Angular 1.4.12 app with nested views. The reason is that some sections of my app have a header/content/footer setup and some do not.

My index page has a single ui-view.

```
  <div ui-view class="top-view"></div>
```

Into that, via ui-router, I load routes that have multiple views;  most of the time, it's a header/content/footer, such as `home.html`:

```
<div ui-view="header" class="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content" class="site-content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer" class="footer"></div>
```

Using a route such as:

```
  angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html'
        },
        'header@home': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
        },
        'content@home': {
          controller: 'HomeController as hc',
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.content.html'
        },
        'footer@home': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

There are links on the content html and the header html with swaps the 3 views for another stub page like `home.html` above with 1, 2, or all 3 subviews (header, content, and/or footer).

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it's working so far.

My roadblock now is trying to use resolves for the routes.  For example, let's say the `HomeController` needs data from a service.  In other apps, I'd use a resolve, such as:

```
    resolve: {
      PeopleResolve: function (MockDataFactory) {
        return MockDataFactory.query({filename: 'ds_users'});
      }
    },
```

However, when I try adding this to the routes.js file as shown above, the page does not load (no console errors, which is confusing, just a blank page).

```
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      resolve: {
        PeopleResolve: function (MockDataFactory) {
          return MockDataFactory.query({ filename: 'ds_users' });
        }
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html'
        },
        'header@home': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
        },
        'content@home': {
          controller: 'HomeController as hc',
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.content.html'
        },
        'footer@home': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

### UPDATE 1:

Based on a comment I added this to my app.module, found here after a search:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).run(function ($state, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(error);
});
```

});

Comment: try adding a state change error handler in a run block and inspect the error object. Does the `MockDataFactory.query()` method work elsewhere?

Comment: See my update.  I added a run block but not sure how to get the error anywhere I can view it.  This factory works in other projects.

Comment: just log it instead of using `$state.go()`

Comment: Also assuming that `query()` is part of `$resource` could try returning the `$resource` promise. A plunker demo that reproduces problem would help

Comment: The error is `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- MockDataFactory`  I guess I haven't loaded angular resource in this app?

Comment: That should have been showing up in dev tools console. You need to include the script and inject as module and as dependency when you use it

Comment: yes, i checked and i have it loaded.

Comment: Not injecting it as dependency properly then in factory and possibly forgot to inject module as dependency in main module declaration

Comment: Injection errors in resolve don't show up in the console apparently.
What is your MockDataFactory code?

Comment: I got it.  I indeed forgot to inject the `ngResource` dependency in my app module.  This is what happens sometimes when you copy and paste from 1 app to another.

Comment: Odd that it never complained about this in the console, and that the app ran anyway.

Comment: Was just wondering same...typically would break whole app

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION:

The error (thanks [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)) tipped me off to the fact I never injected the `ngResource` module, even though I linked to the `angular-resource.js` in my index.html.

The factory in my promise was the first use in this app of `$resource`, and using it broke the app -- surprisingly with no console errors until I added the run block.